# Crystal Reports | Case Statement in Select Expert

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm looking to filter 1 group of records based upon a parameter. I still want to include the other groups, however. This is where I'm at now, in the select expert:

```
{name_full.NAMETYPE} = "a" and
(if {GENERIC.GROUPTAG} in ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"] OR
{GENERIC.GROUPTAG} = "L" and
{MEMBERSHIP_FULL.MEMBTYPE} = "IALS" and
{SUBSCRIPTIONLEVEL_FULL.SUBLTYPE} = "life" THEN TRUE)
```

There has to be a better/more efficient way to do this, but I'm at a loss.

I'm using Crystal Reports XI with an Oracle DB.

Comment: Couldn't able to understand exactly.... filtering one group and retaining data for other groups...are you discussing about the single report or multiple reports

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, I'm filtering one group while retaining data for all other groups. This is currently a single report.

Comment: If that is the case then you shouldn't be apply filtering in record selection formula instead you should apply local filtering in report itself

Comment: In the section expert with the suppress formulae?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Group suppression statements worked.